# Specialization doesn't contain data that's declared in the primary template

Tags: c++, templates

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void load() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class CustomConfig : public Base {
public:
    const T& getData() { return data; }
    T data;
};

template<>
class CustomConfig<std::set<uint32_t>> {
public:
    virtual void load() {
        this->data = {4, 5, 6};
    }
};
```

I don't know why I got the error:

```
class CustomConfig<std::set<unsigned int> >' has no member named 'data'
```

**REAL CASE**

In fact, I got such an issue: I need a virtual function, but it's return type is not unique, it may be a `std::set`, a `std::vector`, `std::list` or some other types. Then I was thinking the template technique might help. That's why I defined the class `template<typename T> class CustomConfig`.

I hope this was not a serious XY problem... Obviously I misunderstood how template class works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide an alternative to the other answers, which all say you must add your data member, there's another option which is to derive from a template instantiation instead:

```
class CustomConfigSetOfUInt : public CustomConfig<std::set<uint32_t>> {
public:
    void load() override {
        this->data = {4, 5, 6};
    }
};
```

If your `CustomConfig` provides other generalized functionality that would benefit from being done in the class template, then you might prefer this approach.  Your design in general is a bit uncomfortable and does seem to have a "relaxed" attitude toward encapsulation either way.  You may want to have a deeper think about it.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thanks. In fact, I got such an issue: I need a virtual function, but it's return type is not unique, it may be a `std::set`, a `std::vector` or `std::list`. Then I  was thinking the template technique may help. That's why I defined the class `template<typename T> class CustomConfig`.

Answer (score 1):

The specialization is a brand-new class (relative to the primary template), you have to declare the data member for it too (also the inheritting). E.g.

```
template<>
class CustomConfig<std::set<uint32_t>> : public Base {
public:
    virtual void load() {
        this->data = {4, 5, 6};
    }
    const std::set<uint32_t>& getData() { return data; }
    std::set<uint32_t> data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`CustomConfig<std::set<uint32_t>>` is a *specialization* of `CustomConfig<T>`, ie it *replaces* `CustomConfig<T>` when `T` is `std::set<uint32_t>`, it does not *derive* from `CustomConfig<T>` like you are thinking. As such, it does not inherit any of the members of `CustomConfig<T>`.

The two are completely separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

That specialisation does not inherit from the template class, it is instead used in place of the templated class for a specific data type.

So it gets no `data` or `load()`, you have to provide them yourself, such as with:

```cpp
template<>
class CustomConfig<std::set<uint32_t>> : public Base {
public:
    virtual void load() {
        this->data = {4, 5, 6};
    }
    const std::set<uint32_t> &getData() { return data; }
    std::set<uint32_t> data;
};
```

---

In any case, it's often a good idea to steer clear of more "generic" underlying types, as that can be a great assistance in discovering and repairing issues. By that, I mean something like type definitions to make things clearer:

```
using ConfigIntSet = std::set<uint32_t>; // Use *specific* type.
template<>
class CustomConfig<ConfigIntSet> : public Base {
public:
    virtual void load() {
        this->data = {4, 5, 6};
    }
    ConfigIntSet data;
};
```